# How to randomly mix N arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have a list of N numpy arrays of the same shape. I need to combine them into one array in the following way. Each element of the output array should be randomly taken from the corresponding position of one of the input array.

For example, if I need to decide what value to use at position [2,0,7], I take all the values locate at this position in all N input arrays. So, I get N values and I choose one value randomly.

To make it a bit more complex. I would like assign a probability to each input array so that probabilities of values to be selected depends on which input array it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

x = np.random.choice(np.arange(10), (2,3,4))  # pass probabilities with p=...
N = 10
a = [k*np.ones_like(x) for k in range(N)]  # list of N arrays of same shape
y = np.empty(a[0].shape)  # output array

# Generate list of all indices of arrays in a (no matter what shape, this is
# handled with *) and set elements of output array y.
for index in list(it.product(*list(np.arange(n) for n in x.shape))):
    y[index] = a[x[index]][index]
# a[x[index]] is the array chosen at a given index.
# a[x[index]][index] is the element of this array at the given index.

# expected result with the choice of list a: x==y is True for all elements
```

The "more complex part" should be handled with the parameter `p` of [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). Anything else should be explained in the comments. With the use of `*` this should work for arbitrary shape of the arrays in `a` (I hope).

Answer (score 0):

Let us treat this using only numpy built ins: it will be faster than a for loop.

```
import numpy as np

# N = 3 dummy arrays for the example
a = np.zeros([4, 5])
b = 10 * np.ones([4, 5])
c = 2 * b

arr = np.array([a, b, c])  # this is a 3D array containing your N arrays
N = arr.shape[0]

idx = np.random.choice(range(N), 4 * 5)  # 4 and 5 are the common dimensions of your N arrays

# treating this a a 1D problem, but treating as 2D is possible too.
arr.reshape(N, 20)[idx.ravel(), np.arange(20)].reshape(4, 5)
```

If you want to have different probabilities, you can pass a parameter p to np.random.choice (an array of shape (N,) which must sum to 1):

```
idx_p = np.random.choice(range(n_arr), 4 * 5, p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7])
arr.reshape(n_arr, 20)[idx_p.ravel(), np.arange(20)].reshape(4, 5)
```

This gives:

```
# first result:
array([[  0.,   0.,   0.,  20.,  10.],
       [ 20.,   0.,  20.,   0.,  10.],
       [  0.,  10.,   0.,  10.,   0.],
       [ 10.,  20.,  10.,   0.,  10.]])
# second result with many 20, a few 10 and fewer 0:
array([[ 10.,   0.,  20.,  20.,  20.],
       [ 20.,   0.,  20.,  20.,  20.],
       [ 10.,  20.,  20.,  20.,  10.],
       [ 20.,  10.,  20.,  20.,  20.]])
```